# Compare 2 maps together with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

@Julien : I see no point in downvoting a question that could be useful to many beginners. That's ridiculous to see so much hate, your comment (which I respected) was more than enough.

I am working on geopandas and I try to compare 2 maps of NYC, based on their BoroCode (BoroCode & Borocode2).

Please find the code that you can reproduce at home :

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas

# We import the database of NYC and we plot it : 
df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
ax1 = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ax1

# Then I want to make another dataframe which has also a BoroCode column  : 
df_tmp1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 5], [2.7, 4], [5.3, 3], [7, 1], [20, 2]], index = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], columns = ['BoroCode2', 'BoroCode'])
df_tmp1

Out [4] : 
    BoroCode2   BoroCode
0   1.1     5
1   2.7     4
2   5.3     3
3   7.0     1
4   20.0    2


# Now I merge both dataframes : 
df1 = pd.merge(df, df_tmp1, on = ['BoroCode'])

# And I can make to maps based on their BoroCode : 

map1 = df1.plot(column='BoroCode', cmap='tab10', figsize=(15, 5), legend=True)
```

[image: map1]

```
map2 = df1.plot(column='BoroCode2', cmap='tab10', figsize=(15, 5), legend=True)
```

[image: map2]

And then, I want to show side-by-side the `map1` & `map2` togethers in the same row. Just to compare them.

I have tested with `subplot`, but I think I don't master it well yet.

Because I am not familiar with the tutorials as they use functions to make plots and scatters from scratch with `ax`, `x`, and `y`, `axes`, etc. And I am a beginner so I can't succeed to adapt the code to my case.

I just want to show those maps together. Nothing more.

Could somebody help me to show such a way ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Show us your code. Otherwise what else can we do other than repeating what's already in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subplots in matplotlib are created e.g. as

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15,5))
```

Geopandas' [`plot`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot) accepts an argument `ax` to which to supply the axes to plot to.

```
df1.plot(column='BoroCode', cmap='tab10', legend=True, ax=ax1)
df2.plot(column='BoroCode2', cmap='tab10', legend=True, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: Dear @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have edited my first post just to be sure we have the same understanding. Please, could you chck and come back to me ? Thank you very much !

Comment: I think my answer still applies. But I updated it with more from your example.

Comment: Thanlk you so much ! It works ! 

![map3](https://image.ibb.co/gDZvYo/index3.png) 

As the units are the same for both maps, do you know how to commonize one legend for both please ?

Comment: You would need to set the same limits for both data, via `vmin` and `vmax`.